# How do streams stop?

Tags: java-8, java-stream, infinite

I was wondering when I created my own infinite stream with `Stream.generate` how the Streams which are in the standard library stop...

For example when you have a list with records:

```
List<Record> records = getListWithRecords();
records.stream().forEach(/* do something */);
```

The stream won't be infinite and running forever, but it will stop when all items in the list are traversed. But how does that work? The same functionality applies for the stream created by `Files.lines(path)` (source: http://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-stream-read-a-file-line-by-line/).

And a second question, how can a stream created with `Stream.generate` be stopped in the same manner then?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finite streams simply aren’t created via `Stream.generate`.

The standard way of implementing a stream, is to implement a [`Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/Spliterator.html), sometimes using [the `Iterator` detour](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterators.html#spliteratorUnknownSize-java.util.Iterator-int-). In either case, the implementation has a way to report an end, e.g. when `Spliterator.tryAdvance` returns `false` or its `forEachRemaining` method just returns, or in case of an `Iterator` source, when `hasNext()` returns `false`.

A `Spliterator` may even report the expected number of elements before the processing begins.

Streams, created via one of the factory methods inside the `Stream` interface, like `Stream.generate` may be implemented either, by a `Spliterator` as well or using internal features of the stream implementation, but regardless of how they are implemented, you don’t get hands on this implementation to change their behavior, so the only way to make such a stream finite, is to chain a `limit` operation to the stream.

If you want to create a non-empty finite stream that is not backed by an array or collection and none of the existing stream sources fits, you have to implement your own `Spliterator` and [create a stream out of it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.Spliterator-boolean-). As told above, you can use an existing method to create a `Spliterator` out of an `Iterator`, but you should resists the temptation to use an `Iterator` just because it’s familiar. A `Spliterator` is not hard to implement:

```
/** like {@code Stream.generate}, but with an intrinsic limit */
static <T> Stream<T> generate(Supplier<T> s, long count) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(
               new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T>(count, Spliterator.SIZED) {
        long remaining=count;

        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
            if(remaining<=0) return false;
            remaining--;
            action.accept(s.get());
            return true;
        }
    }, false);
}
```

From this starting point, you can add overrides for the `default` methods of the `Spliterator` interface, weighting development expense and potential performance improvements, e.g.

```
static <T> Stream<T> generate(Supplier<T> s, long count) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(
               new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T>(count, Spliterator.SIZED) {
        long remaining=count;

        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
            if(remaining<=0) return false;
            remaining--;
            action.accept(s.get());
            return true;
        }

        /** May improve the performance of most non-short-circuiting operations */
        @Override
        public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super T> action) {
            long toGo=remaining;
            remaining=0;
            for(; toGo>0; toGo--) action.accept(s.get());
        }
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: Why avoid using an iterator to define the spliterator? I just saw that BufferedReader.lines() uses this approach to create his finite stream for example.

Comment: `BufferedReader.lines()` is a good example. Look at the implementation of `next()` and [`hasNext()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/BufferedReader.java?av=f#566) and how they have to keep state between invocations. In contrast, a spliterator is straight-forward, a single method is needed: `tryAdvance(Consumer<? super String> c) { String line=readLine(); if(line==null) return false; c.accept(line); return true; }` and that’s it. Simpler to implement (add the exception handling and still half the code size) and no wrapper needed…

Comment: @WillD: it’s safe in the sense that it will work correctly when using `Stream.parallel()`. The `Spliterator` itself doesn’t need to be thread safe as the Stream will not access it concurrently. The parallel performance could be improved by adding a dedicated `trySplit` implementation, however, note that the same result can be achieved by simply using `IntStream.range(0, count).mapToObj(i -> supplier.get())`. The code of this answer is more a template for solving more specialized tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a generic workaround for this

```
public class GuardedSpliterator<T> implements Spliterator<T> {

  final Supplier<? extends T> generator;

  final Predicate<T> termination;

  final boolean inclusive;

  public GuardedSpliterator(Supplier<? extends T> generator, Predicate<T> termination, boolean inclusive) {
    this.generator = generator;
    this.termination = termination;
    this.inclusive = inclusive;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
    T next = generator.get(); 
    boolean end = termination.test(next);
    if (inclusive || !end) {
      action.accept(next);
    }
    return !end;
  }

  @Override
  public Spliterator<T> trySplit() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
  }

  @Override
  public long estimateSize() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
  }

  @Override
  public int characteristics() {
    return Spliterator.ORDERED;
  }

}
```

**Usage is pretty easy:**

```
GuardedSpliterator<Integer> source = new GuardedSpliterator<>(
    ()  -> rnd.nextInt(),
    (i) -> i > 10,
    true
);

Stream<Integer> ints = StreamSupport.stream(source, false);

ints.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
```

Comment: There is no reason to implement interface methods by throwing `UnsupportedOperationException`, when there are well defined fallback values, i.e. `estimateSize()` should return `Long.MAX_VALUE` for “unknown size” and `trySplit()` should return `null` when it doesn’t support splitting. But when you extend `Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator` instead, you even get splitting support, without needing to implement these methods.